# Перенаправление 301 редирект

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Добрый день! Не так давно на достаточно известном блоге, появилась статья посвящённая перенаправлению, 301 редирект в .htaccess.
Где автор советует производить редерект, как на главное зеркало с **WWW** или без, так и с защищённого протокола **https://** на **http://** и даже приводит пример:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abrek-ad-abra.ru $1 [R=301,L]
```

Что превело меня в тупик. Насколько я знаю, гугл наоборот для популяризации **https**, даёт дополнительные бонусы сайтам, которые его используют
http://habrahabr.ru/post/232629/.

Я считаю, что если есть SSL, лучше направлять на него, а не с него.
Зачем тогда использовать защищенное соединение, что бы с него перенаправлять на обычное? Подскажите пожалуйста если я что-то не так понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен. Очевидных причин не вижу. Может приведете ссылочку где Вы это прочитали?

Comment: Поддерживаю - лучше с `http` на `https`, даже не учитывая про гугл!

Comment: Спасибо! Получается, что не стоит принимать советы от SEO гуру за чистую монету, большинство из которых всего лишь теоретики, зарабатывающие только ведением блога.